# Cannot add Heroku DNS target in BigRock

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting

I have an application hosted on **Heroku** server in free tier service. I'm adding a custom domain purchased from **BigRock**.

When adding a custom domain in Heroku it gives me a `DNS Target` -

`abc-def-somelongstring.herokudns.com`.

Then I went to manage console of BigRock and try to add **Name Server** and pasting the above target to the **Name server 2** input field. But it is throwing an error.

> NameServer abc-def-jvxgdae599y1e3ftm3bijxxc.herokudns.com is not a valid Nameserver

I had a chat with BigRock support team and they are saying that **the format of the name server is incorrect.**

Since it is a free tier Heroku is not letting me open a support ticket. Please help. I'm a beginner so really don't know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
The value you entered can be used as cname not as name server because  it is domain url.Just to point site to heroku you have 2 options :

1.CNAME: Add the domain to your heroku app => heroku domains:add domainname

Go to your domain service provider account and update/add a "www" CName DNS record and point it to your heroku app (e.g. appname.herokuapp.com)


2.PointDNS: This is addin available on heroku which can help in pointing site to heroku hosting.Steps to use pointDNS in you application hjosted on heroku :

Add the domain to your heroku app => heroku domains:add domainname

    Go to resources-> add `PointDNS` addon,
    a.Verify by clicking on pointDNS
    b.Copy all NS records from bigrock to pointDNS
    c.Update NS issued by pointDNS (dns8.pointhq.com,dns12.pointhq.com) in bigrocks


Note: If you are ever going to add ssl on your website, then you need to move your dns records to heroku with pointDNS(addon available on heroku - free for 1 domain and 20 dns records).
```

Answer (score 0):

That value *isn't* a name server; it's just a domain. The expectation is that you have your DNS somewhere else, e.g. with the company you bought the domain from, and that you configure a record there pointing to the Heroku domain.

Within the BigRock DNS control panel, add a `CNAME` record that points to the domain Heroku gave you. For example, you might set a `CNAME` record from `www.yourdomain.com` whose value is `abc-def-jvxgdae599y1e3ftm3bijxxc.herokudns.com`.

Comment: I have added it `CNAME` record. But still, it doesn't work. What should I do now?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik, DNS changes take some time to propagate. Give it some time.

Comment: As of now, I'm taking help of Domain Forwarding to redirect the site to `abc.herokuapp.com`

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik, I'm not sure what you mean by Domain Forwarding. Many domain registrars make up their own names for things. Is this an HTTP redirect? Does your browser's URL update to show `yourapp.herokuapp.com`, or does it keep your custom domain?

Comment: They maybe that's what BigRock calls a `CNAME` record. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please open a command window and run `nslookup www.yourdomain.com` and see what comes back. I'm expecting to see the `herokudns.com` value.

Comment: Yeah, I got `abc-def-jvxgdae599y1e3ftm3bijxxc.herokudns.com`

Comment: Okay, that's good. You have a `CNAME` set up. I think you already did that yesterday, so I'm not sure if your "domain forwarding" did anything or whether your machine just picked up the DNS changes. The `CNAME` record is the correct solution here.

Comment: I have removed the CNAME but "domain forwarding" is still present. But now everything is working for me. Of course, I don't know how 

Comment: You might be using domain forwarding with masking

Answer (score 0):

You might be using domain forwarding with masking

Comment: I'm using domain forwarding though, but masking I have no idea about. Unless it is happening under the hood

Comment: Yes coz keeping the same url can be achieved by cname or masking